# ‘Mage_Magenotification_Helper_Data’ not found

Tags: magento

I install extension Instant Search by Magestore.after that i see this error.(http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-instant-search.html)

Fatal error: Class ‘Mage_Magenotification_Helper_Data’ not found in /home/**********/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 546

I am facing this problem. I have installed Product Instant Search .

http://www.magestore.com/product-instant-search.html

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Sandeep, check on codes helper function is not working in config.xml,Please put config.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still get this error-message, you have to install the Magenotification Extension from Magestore.

To install the extension, checkout the extension from google code:

```
svn checkout http://my-wholesale.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ my-wholesale-read-only
```

then copy the directory **my-wholesale-read-only/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification** to your **/app/code/local/Magestore/** directory and create a **Magestore_Magenotification.xml** under **app/etc/modules/**.

Answer (score 0):

Double check all the module files have been uploaded properly, refresh all the caches and ensure the compiler is off (or recompile). It is most likely the XML cache needs refreshed or the compiler needs recompiled.